# Retrieve the value from a void method

Tags: methods, overriding, void

I have a method:

```
@Override
```

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

```
    float [] values = event.values;
    float altitude;
    altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,values[0]);


}
```

How can I access to the value of "altitude" from another class?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not, it looks like you are using java? and you are overriding a function so returning it may not be an option.

so an easy solution would be to declare altitude as a class variable, not in the function and provide a accessor/geter function.

```
class Someclass
{
    private float altitude;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {
        float [] values = event.values;
        altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,values[0]);        
    }

    //function to get altitude
    public float getAltitude()
    {
        return altitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using android and I need to retrieve the value of a smartphone sensor (Barometer). Your proposal always returns the value 0.

Comment: did you make sure to remove the "float altitude;" line from the function? and are you sure it is getting set correctly? it will stay as 0 until the onSensorChanged function gets called

Comment: Yes I am sure about these modifications and here the class where I access to the altitude value

Comment: are you registering your call back with  "SensorManager.registerListener" ? is this on a real phone or a emulator? does the phone have a pressure sensor in it?

Comment: Yes I registered the call back with "SensorMana ...." and I am using a real phone that integrates a pressure sensor and here the code of the class